# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function

Tags: javascript, rating

I am trying to show rating stars using bootstrap plugin but I got the error saying
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function, here is how my code looks like 
I have checked jquery calls and other solutions but with no result

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Google leads </title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
        <meta content="Preview page of Metronic Admin Theme #2 for bootstrap advanced color pickers" name="description" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />
        <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&amp;subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
        <link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/global/plugins/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
        <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
        <link href="../assets/global/css/components.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/global/css/plugins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
        <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
        <link href="../assets/layouts/layout2/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../assets/layouts/layout2/css/themes/blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
        <link href="../assets/layouts/layout2/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- END THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /> 

  
        

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/global/plugins/star-rating-svg/src/css/star-rating-svg.css">
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/global/plugins/star-rating.css">

 
        </head>
   
           
              
            <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           
            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
            <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
            <script src="../assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
            <script src="../assets/pages/scripts/components-color-pickers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            
   <!---->
   
 
 
            <!-- END THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
                 <script src="../assets/global/plugins/star-rating-svg/src/jquery.star-rating-svg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js"
             type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script>

         

         some js code


     </script>

             
  <script>
 $().ready(function() {
  $('.rating-loading').rating();

});
 



 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: up to [rating plugin](https://github.com/nashio/star-rating-svg) documentation which I think this is the one you use .. you need to use `.starRating()` not `.rating()` ..

Comment: In fact I m using bootstrap star rating http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating/demo

Comment: put it in $(document).ready(function(){}  block, it worked for me for  krajee bootstrap star rating plugin, the one that you have also

Answer (score 1):

On your side try changing this line, `$().ready(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function(){`

I couldn't tell you what else you might need because all of your assets to the document are relative to you and not available to the snippet.